# best approach to parse json response in spring boot

Tags: java, spring

I am consuming a rest-end point using rest template which returns below josn messages.
object Wrappers is better approach or json object parsing is better ?

```
[
      {
      "id": "UAMwcI",
      "messageId": "PyXPTk-6XUBhbONWZ2DOw3___pFykwV5bQ",
      "timestamp": 1574330759814,
      "type": "MESSAGESENT",
      "initiator": {"user":       {
         "userId": 345315370604341,
         "firstName": "Sanjeet",
         "lastName": "Mohanty",
         "displayName": "Sanjeet Mohanty",
         "email": "Sanjeet.mohanty@db.com",
         "username": "Sanjeet.mohanty@db.com"
      }},
      "payload": {"messageSent": {"message":       {
         "messageId": "PyXPTk-6XUBhbONWZ2DOw3___pFykwV5bQ",
         "timestamp": 1574330759814,
         "message": "<div data-format=\"PresentationML\" data-version=\"2.0\" class=\"wysiwyg\"><p>test 2 <\/p><\/div>",
         "data": "{}",
         "user":          {
            "userId": 345315370604341,
            "firstName": "Sanjeet",
            "lastName": "Mohanty",
            "displayName": "Sanjeet Mohanty",
            "email": "Sanjeet.mohanty@db.com",
            "username": "Sanjeet.mohanty@db.com"
         },
         "stream":          {
            "streamId": "cL7jzEDwLxX_gN7D1QbMQn___pP73Ad6dA",
            "streamType": "IM"
         },
         "externalRecipients": false,
         "userAgent": "DESKTOP-40.0.0-10726-Windows-7-Chrome-76.0.3809.87",
         "originalFormat": "com.symphony.messageml.v2"
      }}}
   },
      {
      "id": "Bvua7t",
      "messageId": "8usJ_xioHKkRrevhyn38wn___pFykv-WbQ",
      "timestamp": 1574330761321,
      "type": "MESSAGESENT",
      "initiator": {"user":       {
         "userId": 345315370604341,
         "firstName": "Sanjeet",
         "lastName": "Mohanty",
         "displayName": "Sanjeet Mohanty",
         "email": "Sanjeet.mohanty@db.com",
         "username": "Sanjeet.mohanty@db.com"
      }},
      "payload": {"messageSent": {"message":       {
         "messageId": "8usJ_xioHKkRrevhyn38wn___pFykv-WbQ",
         "timestamp": 1574330761321,
         "message": "<div data-format=\"PresentationML\" data-version=\"2.0\" class=\"wysiwyg\"><p>test 3<\/p><\/div>",
         "data": "{}",
         "user":          {
            "userId": 345315370604341,
            "firstName": "Sanjeet",
            "lastName": "Mohanty",
            "displayName": "Sanjeet Mohanty",
            "email": "Sanjeet.mohanty@db.com",
            "username": "Sanjeet.mohanty@db.com"
         },
         "stream":          {
            "streamId": "cL7jzEDwLxX_gN7D1QbMQn___pP73Ad6dA",
            "streamType": "IM"
         },
         "externalRecipients": false,
         "userAgent": "DESKTOP-40.0.0-10726-Windows-7-Chrome-76.0.3809.87",
         "originalFormat": "com.symphony.messageml.v2"
      }}}
   }
]
```

Comment: the next time you can put it directly into code with: ``` for start and end

Comment: If you have access to JSONObject, its literally new JSONObject(jsonString);

Answer (score 0):

there is a lot of Liberaiyes to serialize deserialize JSON.

if you have Pojo class match the return value from your rest API
you could use for instance Jackson to do the job

```
PojoClass mypojo = new ObjectMapper().readValue(JsonString, PojoClass.class);
```

OR simply converted to JSonNode and iterate over the Nodes

```
JsonNode jsonNode = new ObjectMapper().readTree(JsonString);
```

check the link for more info 
https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-object-mapper-tutorial